# Problems Working with 2 spinners

Tags: android

I am just a beginner in Android
I'm trying to implement 2 spinners ,first one displays the groupname and other should display the id's associated with the groupname.
But every time i select a different groupname the id just gets appended in the spinner .
I would be glad if anyone could help me out with this.

Comment: What you want if `groupname` is change then it's related `groupid` is select in second Spinner.

Comment: Put some code so someone can help you

Comment: @Divya please provide some code so we can help